# How show raw html with slot in component vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```
<template slot="content">
   <form-label class="align-left">パスワードの再設定を行います。</form-label>
</template>
```

How can i show `<form-label class="align-left">パスワードの再設定を行います。</form-label>` as text for slot in component in Vuejs?

```
Vue.component("raw-text", {
    template: `<div>
                 <span ref="source"><slot></slot></span>
                </div>`,
    mounted: function() {
         this.$el.innerText = this.$refs.source.innerHTML;
     }});
```

I've tried this, but $refs.source.innerHTML is compiled source which i'm not expect that.

i expect the output as:
 `<form-label class="align-left">パスワードの再設定を行います。</form-label>`
 but the actual is `<div class="align-left nts-label"><label><!----> パスワードの再設定を行います。</label></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Use  [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML) directives:

```js
Vue.component("raw-text", {
data: function() {
  return {
    slotHtml: 'パスワードの再設定を行います'
  }
},
template: `<div>
             <span ref="source"><slot v-html="slotHtml"></slot></span>
            </div>`,
});
```

Comment: i want can add source in html with slot tag and show full source as raw text (can contain html tag).

Comment: and i want that text can be showed in with format in html